# Convert a Flash movie that only appears to have one frame to AVI

Tags: flash, avi, flash-cs6

I have never used Flash before but have been given an FLA file which I would like to convert to an AVI file and upload to Youtube.

When the file is opened in Adobe Flash CS6, only 1 frame appears in the timeline.

I have discovered that one of the layers on the timeline is a movieclip.

If I go to library in the right pane, and double click this item it opens up in the timeline as 360 frames long and made up of many layers and folders.

Is there a way I can export this as an AVI file?

I have attempted right clicking on it and selecting "Convert to Compiled Clip" but this doesn't seem to give any AVI options.

I have also tried going to File > Export > Export Movie and selecting AVI, however the exported movie only comes out as 1 frame/second long.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: ctrl+enter in cs6 will give you an output .swf. You can convert .swf to avi using format factory(Video conversion software).

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+enter in cs6 will give you an output .swf. You can convert .swf to avi using format factory(Video conversion software)

Comment: I've tried converting the swf file in FF but get Error0x1:Incorrect function. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: No idea but you can try online convertors.

Answer (score 0):

In the main timelne first frame shows as gray box with dot. Select 1st frame and see what area selected in main window. If there are only 1 object with bounding box (that's good), select them with mouse in main window and change object type from MovieClip to Graphics in Properties panel. Then point cursor in 360 frame and press F5. Now try export movie with File->Export->Export Movie.

But if that MovieClip (now Graphics) contains another movies, they will show only their 1st frame.

Also you can write AVI from SWF with http://swftoaviconverter.org/ or any Screen Recording Software (google will help)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Format Factory for convert video.
U can try it : http://betdownload.com/format-factory-8-download